# How can I Remove HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error message from Apache Tomcat/9.0.68

Tags: apache, tomcat, coldfusion, lucee

I am working in Lucee coldfusion and in there I am using Framework one (FW1) framework and in framework one we got a functionality using which we can route URLs and is working fine as well in Adobe coldfusion where I am using IIS but when I am using lucee with Apache Tomcat/9.0.68 I am getting HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error message.

How can I solve this?

I am expecting this:-

[image]

but I am getting this:-

[image]

Comment: I'd bet something is wrong with your Tomcat configuration (e.g. wrong wwwroot) or a file permission issue. What do you get when you hit http://127.0.0.1:8888 ?